# Sending data by JSON

Tags: json, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I want to send JSON from desktop application to the server with mvc wepApi.
this is my desktop application code ,that convert data to the JSON and send it.

```
 private void btnAddUserType_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       UserType userType = new UserType();
        userType.UserTypeName = txtUserTypeName.Text;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userType);


        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:3852/api/default1");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
        streamWriter.Write(json);


        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
        var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

and this is my web api

```
 // POST api/default1
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        UserTypeRepository bl = new UserTypeRepository();
        DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(UserType));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
        UserType u = new UserType();
         u = (UserType)js.ReadObject(stream);
        bl.Add(u);
    }
```

but when post api is calling the `Value is null`.
why?

Comment: Hmmm... Can you try using content type `application/json`? Also, in that case, you might try `public void Post([FromBody]UserType value)` - you shouldn't have to deserialize JSON yourself.

Also, check what you receive by debugging and inspecting the Request.Form object (and see what is available under what key).

Comment: @Gerino , It did not work!

Comment: its a easy question for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        using(var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            streamWriter.Write(json);
```

You are not flushing nor closing the stream, so basically the data never gets to the api.

My code:

Program.cs - Console App

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var user = new UserModel {Id = 4, FirstName = "Michael", LastName = "Angelo"};
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:56506/api/Values/");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using(var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            streamWriter.Write(json);



        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
        var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(responseText);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

UserModel.cs - some data class

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

ValuesController.cs - WebApi controller from template

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public UserModel[] Get()
    {
        return UserProvider.Instance.Get(); // returns some test data
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public UserModel Get(int id)
    {
        return new UserModel{Id=1,FirstName="John",LastName="Smith"};
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]UserModel value)
    {
        if (value == null)  // BREAKPOINT HERE, just to see what's in value
        {
            var x = value;
        }
    }

}
```

WebApiConfig.cs - default config with added line about Json, but IT WORKS WITHOUT IT -it's so that I can test GET easily in browser etc. ;)

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result of running console app]